# how to parse large files in less time using stanford parser java

Tags: java, nlp, text-parsing, stanford-nlp

I need to parse hundreds of large files using Stanford parsed, when I parse 20 files it is taking 2 hours to parse, is there any way to do this in less time.

below is my code to parse single file

```
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();

for (List<HasWord> sentence : new DocumentPreprocessor("C://sample.txt")) {
    Tree parse = lp.apply(sentence);
    GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
    Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();

    pw.print(parse.pennString());
    pw.println(tdl.toString());

}
```

Thanks

Comment: How big are your files?

Comment: How large are the files? how much memory is allocated to the JVM? If you're going to continue using the same code, you'll have to improve the machine or allocate more memory to the JVM to decrease execution time.

Comment: Did you analyse where most of the time is spent? io, parser, garbage collector, etc. Otherwise it is a question like: Why is my car so slow? fuel, engine damage, gear drive, driver problem,...

Comment: almost 1mb to 5mb files

Comment: As far as I remember, complexity of the PCFG parser is cubical to the sentence length (and linear to the size of the corpus of rules or something). It may be feasible not to parse sentences longer than 20-30 words. Parsing is a time consuming task :) You've probably checked this out but I'll mention it anyways: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml